# Reading From local folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

In C# code, if I refer to a file by just the file name, it's not reading it from the local folder. Instead it refers to `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\` and throws a `FileNotFoundException`. How do I read from the local folder?

Comment: Are you running this as a service? What do you mean "local folder" is this the Working Directory? Which version of Windows?

Comment: Yes, its the working directory. Where all the code file exists. Yes its a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are referring to the files in the virtual directory. Use `Server.MapPath`

```
filePath = Server.MapPath("~/path/relative/to/site/root/filename")
```